# Routing problems in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got some problems with my routes at the moment.

I have a controller house with function add. Also I have a view in houses/add.html.erb

I call it with domain/houses/add so I got this error: No route matches [GET] "/houses/add"

routes.rb looks like this:

```
 resources :api_users, :as => :users

 get '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
 post '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use only get and post method,
do not use `resources` due to the memory usage.

`match "houses/add" => "houses#add", via: [:get, :post]`

and never use single quote in `routes.rb`

```
get '#{action}' <- this is not working 

get "#{action"  <- this works.



  YOURCONTROLLER.action_methods.each do |action|
    get "CONTROLLER_NAME/#{action}", to: "CONTROLLER_NAME##{action}"
  end
```

Comment: do I have to add for each now method a new route?

Comment: if your method doesn't follow the Rails routing conventions, yes.
there's easy workaround tho. i updated my answer @Felix

Comment: normally they do. I think the problem was the single quote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
resources :api_users, as: :users

# empty for memory concerns
resources :houses, only: [] do
    collection do
         get :add
         post :another_action
    end
end
```

OR if you are only trying to rename new to add then you can do something like this:

```
resources :houses, path_names: { new: 'add' }

# Which will now path /domain/houses/new --> /domain/houses/add
# NOTE* This does not change the actual action name, it will still look for houses#new
```

Something to note about `match` protocols to single route:

[guides.rubyonrails.org/routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
**3.7 HTTP Verb Constraints**

*In general, you should use the get, post, put, patch and delete methods to constrain a route to a particular verb. You can use the match method with the :via option to match multiple verbs at once:*

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
```

*You can match all verbs to a particular route using via: :all:*

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all
```

> Routing both GET and POST requests to a single action has security
>   implications. In general, you should avoid routing all verbs to an
>   action unless you have a good reason to.
>
> 'GET' in Rails won't check for CSRF token. You should never write to
>   the database from 'GET' requests, for more information see the
>   security guide on CSRF countermeasures.